# Issues with merging arrays of objects in MoongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I trying to build an aggregation quarry in MoongoDb that will merge arrays from 
2 different collection (one of the collections is of type TTL). And I facing with 2 issues that I can’t resolve.

**First Issue:**

I would like to merge the `TakenSeats` fields of my temp collations and permanent collection and set the result instead of my correct `TakenSeats` field, Using my aggregation in the bottom i manage to merge the arrays with the `$push` operator, But I cant replace the result field with the `TakenSeats` field that is in my permanent document.

**Second Issue:**

In case that I don’t have any documents in my temp collection, how can I still receive the document from the permanent one?

*Sample of document in the permanent collection: (extracting data from one document)*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d"),
    "showsHall" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b64cb758ad5f81a6cb7e6ae")
    ],
    "movie" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6b614218883ec018d15428")
    ],
    "takenSeats" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 12
        }
    ],
    "showDate" : "8/14/2018",
    "showStartTime" : "3:00 PM",
    "showEndTime" : "5:00 PM",
    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-08T21:49:28.020Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

*From the TTL collection: (extracting data from multiple documents)*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6f35023f64851baa70c61b"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-11T19:12:02.951Z"),
    "showId" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d")
    ],
    "takenSeats" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 22
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 25
        }
    ]
}
```

*This is the aggregation that I used:*

```
db.getCollection('shows').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d") } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "temp",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "showId",
            as: "fromItems"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$fromItems" },
    { "$project": {"takenSeats": { "$setUnion": ["$takenSeats", "$fromItems.takenSeats"]}, _id: 1, showsHall: 1, movie: 1, takenSeats: 1 , showDate: 1, showStartTime: 1, showEndTime: 1 }},   
    {$unwind:"$takenSeats"},
    {$group:{_id: "$_id", takenSeats: {$push : "$takenSeats"} }}, 
])
```

**Result:**

[image: MoonfoDb]

**[Edit]**

I manage to maintain my original data with `$first` operator.
But now i cant resolve issue no 2 (prevent result if null), I tried to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`
in both of the  `unwind` stages but the result is that it pushes an empty array.
My wanted result is that it should `push` to a new array only if there is values to `push`

*This is my aggregation* :

```
    db.getCollection('shows').aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d") } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "temp",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "showId",
                as: "fromItems"
            }
        },
        { $unwind:{path:"$fromItems" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
        { "$project": {"takenSeats": { "$setUnion": ["$takenSeats", "$fromItems.takenSeats"]}, _id: 1, showsHall: 1, movie: 1, showDate: 1, showStartTime: 1, showEndTime: 1 }},   
           {$unwind:{path:"$takenSeats" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
,
        {$group:{
             _id: "$_id", 
             showsHall : { $first: '$showsHall' },
             movie : { $first: '$movie' },
             showDate : { $first: '$showDate' },
             showStartTime : { $first: '$showStartTime' },
             showEndTime : { $first: '$showEndTime' },
             takenSeats: {$push : "$takenSeats"} 
              }
        }      
    ])
```

This is the result that i getting if there is no documents in the temp collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d"),
    "showsHall" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b64cb758ad5f81a6cb7e6ae")
    ],
    "movie" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6b614218883ec018d15428")
    ],
    "showDate" : "8/14/2018",
    "showStartTime" : "3:00 PM",
    "showEndTime" : "5:00 PM",
    "takenSeats" : [ 
        null
    ]
}
```

Comment: After the `$unwind`stage use this `{
     $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$takenSeats" }
   }`

Comment: second issue solve by use ```preserveNullAndEmptyArrays``` property in ```unwind``` as  ```{ $unwind:{path:"$fromItems" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}```

Comment: Please provide sample output data for results you want. so getting more understanding on your first issue.

Comment: Thanks for youre help guys, I am edited my question.
@IftekharDani I tried to use yore solution for issue number 2, But as you can see in my edit that it didnt quite work .

Comment: same condition use for ```{$unwind:"$takenSeats"}``` and check it.

Comment: @IftekharDani Sorry i didn't mention but i did that, It giving me the `takenSeats` as a null

Comment: Please check my answer. that help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Please add ifNull Condition for solution 2

```
db.getCollection('shows').aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d") } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "tempShows",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "showId",
                as: "fromItems"
            }
        },
        { $unwind:{path:"$fromItems" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
        { "$project": {"takenSeats": { $ifNull: [{ "$setUnion": ["$takenSeats", "$fromItems.takenSeats"]}, '$takenSeats'] } ,_id: 1, showsHall: 1, movie: 1, showDate: 1, showStartTime: 1, showEndTime: 1 }},   
           {$unwind:{path:"$takenSeats" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
        {$group:{
             _id: "$_id", 
             showsHall : { $first: '$showsHall' },
             movie : { $first: '$movie' },
             showDate : { $first: '$showDate' },
             showStartTime : { $first: '$showStartTime' },
             showEndTime : { $first: '$showEndTime' },
             takenSeats: {$push : "$takenSeats"} 
              }
        }      
    ])
```